# Http Request forwarding for elastic load balancing of Java EE application

Tags: java, servlets, load-balancing

I am currently investigating possible solutions for flexible load balancing of a streaming application. I will have several nodes running the application that will process and stream content to the users. Documents are spread among any number of servers such that a single machine is responsible for serving requests to the set of documents it hosts.

Thus, I need some kind of broker that knows on which server the requested document resides and that does a forward to that server. I do NOT want to use some `HttpConnection` from the broker and then include the response of that http call into the response of the original request (this will obviously be a bottleneck).

So my question is: How can I forward a request to another server after having analyzed the requests data (`POST`/`GET` params, headers or whatever) and determined the destination server?

Is there already a good load balancer out there that allows me to use some form of hooks to provide the logic of how to determine destination servers (round robin will obviously not work)?

I want to use Tomcat or something similar to host the streaming application and use only the fundamental servlet stack. Any hints to tools or patterns are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option could be looking for [Layer 7 switching](https://devcentral.f5.com/blogs/us/layer-7-switching-load-balancing-layer-7-load-balancing#.USTLRDfw-41) or [URL load balancing](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/app_ntwk_services/data_center_app_services/ace_appliances/vA3_1_0/configuration/slb/guide/classlb.html#wp1021430) hardware.

Answer (score -1):

There are several load balancers which has well defined node selection mechanisms based on request parameters like:

- headers
- request uri
- query parameters

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to some resources? That there is such thing I have already guessed since otherwise it would not be possible to run large scale applications.